# CSLA .NET Architecture

Tags: csla

Is CSLA.NET architecture is a good choice in an enterprise level application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That depends on what you mean by enterprise level... what is the application? Is a desktop application, Web based? Middleware? A shared library?

CSLA has some good and bad points. I've asked a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15241/does-anyone-have-any-real-world-experience-of-csla). Look at that one and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178343/have-you-ever-used-csla#178535)

My criticisms are that it is very verbose, and sometimes over complex and that it encapsulates the data layer within its classes meaning that TDD is tough with it.

However it was designed for business and gives you some brilliant funcitonality straight out of the tin. The [book](http://www.apress.com/book/view/1590596323) is well worth a read.